# Afraid to reboot server 2008 R2

Tags: raid, windows-server-2008-r2

I did a fresh install of server 2008 R2, installed the updates, and then rebooted. The system would not reboot. Windows kept checking for ways to repair, I used a linux disc to verify the drives on raid were fine. Everything checked out.

I then reinstalled windows 2008 R2, and it never made it through the first reboot. So I simply reinstalled again, and now it's running great. I am afraid to reboot at this time. I'm afraid to install the updates and be forced to reboot.

What should I do? This is a production Dell server with new hard drives in it, setup as a Raid 5.

Comment: You need to narrow down the possible causes for this behavior.

Comment: I guess, that's the point of my post. The drives are fine. What else could it be? UEFI?

Comment: If it was UEFI it wouldn't have ever booted...  It seems there is an update that causes this, you need to narrow that update down, to a few choices instead of the several dozen it actually could be.

Comment: Ok, so say I install a few updates at a time, and then suddenly the system won't reboot and I narrow it down to 3 or 4 potential updates...how do I undo the mess with an unbootable system?